# Querying delayed_jobs in Mongo blocks while map reduce is running

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mapreduce, mongoid, delayed-job

I'm using Ruby's delayed_job_mongoid gem to queue some map/reduce jobs in the background. The jobs process just fine, completing in roughly a minute.

Now I'm trying to query the status of the jobs while they are processing, but I'm finding that any query that I perform on the delayed_jobs table while map/reduce is running just hangs there, blocking until all of the jobs have finished.

So for example, if I execute db.delayed_jobs.find() while map/reduce is running, it just sits there until every last job is finished, then it finally displays the contents of the table (which is empty by that point). It's almost as if the entire table is getting locked while the jobs are running. This isn't what I would expect.

I've checked and I'm not running out of database connections. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a limitation of how MongoDB's map reduce works at the moment. For the time being, MongoDB still has DB level locking and map reduce jobs in particular take out both a read and write lock unless the job is explicitly non-atomic.

You can read more about how to make the mapReduce command non-atomic [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#dbcmd.mapReduce) (caveat: this is only available in MongoDB v2.2+).

> If **nonAtomic** is true, the post-processing step will prevent MongoDB from locking the database; however, other clients will be able to read intermediate states of the output collection. Otherwise the map reduce operation must lock the database during post-processing.

MongoDB's [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) is generally a bit more performant than map reduce. However, it is fairly new and it can't quite do all the same things just yet. If you can accomplish the same task via the aggregation framework I'd recommend using that instead.

For your reference, here's a list of operation types and what kinds of locks each operation requires:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#which-operations-lock-the-database